# Terraform variable user inputs long key value pair

Tags: terraform

I am using a 3rd party app called Morpheus (not a fan of it but its enforced)
I built some modules which are easy enough to request the end user selecting a "Catalog item" to be provisioned and asked for name, and drop down list with ex: instance size, etc.

My issue is thou, I need the user to enter in 1 long string of key value pair to be added to an attribute.

for example

```
parameters = [var.params]
```

and the end user inputs in the text field

```
"example1": "value1", "example2": "value2"
```

but of course this does not work. I tried {"example1": "value1", "example2": "value2"}  and

```
parameters = [jsondecode(var.params)]
```

also does not work. Stuck on what / how to request end user to enter in the values in a specific format. The txt box is 1 liner btw :(, hence why im not a fan of morpheus but whatev's

Comment: It is currently unclear what the current result is, and also what the desired result is. Please add these details to the question.

Comment: In addition to what Matt Schuchard mentioned, it would be helpful to say a little more about _why_ this data must be provided as a single encoded string rather than directly as a map value, since the reason for that might lead to suggestions of other solutions that might avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Sorry i am the worst when it comes to expressing what is on my mind =| 

So morpheus only allows for 1 string txt entries . all my above code is resulting in errors via terraform console. i guess what input could i use as a single string for key value pair for terraform to then use?